What qualifies as "guard strips" for attic wiring?
I am working on getting my attic wiring up to U.S. code (ideally a bit beyond it). Currently most of it is strewn over the joists/rafters every which way, much of it not even secured in place with staples.
This question and answer showed me that in addition to fastening down the cables, I'm going to need to add "substantial guard strips" to many of them. I am looking for more detail on how exactly an inspector would expect/like to find those guards implemented.

There are a few spots where several cables run in basically the same direction for a stretch. Would it be acceptable to make the gap between guard strips a few inches wide and fasten multiple cables between them? Or do you need separate guards for each cable?
The code doesn't really give a ruling on this from what I can tell. I imagine there's a point where it'd no longer provide effective protection, but I'm not sure of the limit.

Many of the cables are currently running at a diagonal across the attic. I imagine it would be ideal if they all ran at 90 degrees either parallel or perpendicular to the joists, but that would reguire me replacing the cables since they'd be too short. Is it okay if my guards just follow the cables as laid, or is there a reason other than aesthetics that'd make it worth the cost/effort to replace the wiring?



It seems as though code does not give quantitative tests, but rather imposes the qualitative requirement that guard strips be "substantial." Based on my own experience with inspectors they don't want to be in the position of recommending a solution. Rather, I think you should devise something that you consider "substantial" and practical to implement, and then ask your authority having jurisdiction for their approval of it.

Where they can reasonably be walked or crawled upon substatial is at-least strong enough to bear your weight (or weight of another person)
So 2x4 should might be enough depending on how far the joists are apart and how good the wood itself is etc.

Thanks, @Jasen. That's a slightly different question that what I was asking, but it brings up another important point. All of the references I've found, including the link above, use a 1x2 as the standard guard. However, I think you're correct that if the purpose is to allow walking over it safely, then something stronger should be used. My joists are 16" apart and I'm pretty sure I could snap a 1x2 with a hard step in the middle.
